# Can "to poke at" mean "to point at"?

Tags: word-meaning

my own examples:
**(1a)** *John poked at Mary (with his finger)*.
**(1b)** *John poked (his finger) at Mary*.
As I understand, (1a) = (1b).

Am I right that each of them has two meanings:
**(2)** *John touched Mary (with his finger)*.
**(3)** *John pointed at Mary (with his finger)*. — (that is, without touching; in order to show somebody that it was Mary who did something)

Comment: AFAIK, *poke* means touching, directly or with an object. 1b *might* be used coloquially to mean point at, though I've not seen that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they both do indeed have two different meanings.

Poke means to prod at or push (in the direction of something), usually with a finger(index), stick or something slender.

It all depends on context.

> John poked at Mary with his finger.

Mary is the direct object here. She is being poked because her name directly follows 'poked'.
You can figure out what the direct object is by asking: "what does he poke?"

> John poked his finger at Mary.

Referencing my last sentence: "what does he poke?"
In  this context, he is poking his finger, the direct object. It directly follows the verb. When one pokes their finger, it is used to point at someone.

See this dictionary for more examples: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/sentences/english/poke

See this dictionary for the different definitions of poke:
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/poke

Comment: _John poked at Mary_ definitely implies physical contact, probably uncomfortable. _Poke at_ isn't usually used for _point to_.